# Implementing bash in c , each line holds { >, <, >> , & , | }

Tags: c, bash, fork, pipe

I'm implementing a simple shell for the `bash` command in `c`   .

I've already parsed the line that I want to work with (I stored the input from `stdin` 
into a `char**` array) . Now I'm left with taking care of the following cases :

```
{ >, <, >> , & , | }
```

little than ,bigger than , redirection , running a command in the background and pipes.

I'm trying to understand something , if I want to do this :

```
someApplication > file
```

or

```
someApplication < file
```

or

```
someApplication >> file
```

Would `forking` do any good ,for implementing these cases ? ( meaning ,the use of `father` & `son` processes )

The way I see it , only if I have a pipe , like ‫‪`ls|grep great‬‬`  , then `fork` would be much more productive since one process would present the files in the directory , and the other one would use the input from the son for completing the right side of the pipe.

Thanks .

**EDIT:**

```
void handleLessThan(char** arguments , int * argumentsCount)
{
    int fd_fork = fork();
    int fd_sourceFile;
    char sourceFile[30];

    if (fd_fork == 0)  // son is running now
    {
        strcpy(arguments[*argumentsCount],sourceFile);
        fd_sourceFile= open(sourceFile, O_RDONLY);
        dup2(fd_sourceFile, 0); .
        execvp(arguments[0],arguments[1]);
    }

    else
    {
        // parent
            ?? 


    }


}
```

Comment: `little than ,bigger than` Not to be a nitpicker (ok, I'm nitpicking =P) but it's `less than` and `greater than`.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're doing this? bash is already written in C

Comment: @Daenyth: I know . This is HW.

Comment: @Falmarri, you have plenty of rep to go and fix it.

Comment: @CarlNorum: My friend ,I'm not asking you to fix the code. I'm asking you to give me a good reason for using `fork()` for `<` command , and for `>` command , since I can't seem to see the point .

Answer (score 4):

**The one and only standard way to create a process in Unix is to `fork`**.

Now that that's out of the way, here is what I suggest you do for the `command > file` case:

- Get a file descriptor for the file, using `open(2)`
- `fork(2)` a new process
- In the child, before you `execvp(3)`, use `dup2` to redirect `STDOUT_FILENO` into the file descriptor obtained in the first step

#### EDIT

In light of edited question:

- Your `strcpy` arguments are probably reversed
- You probably need to `wait(2)` or `waitpid(2)` on the parent branch

Comment: Do you suggest to do the same with the other cases - use `fork()` also ?

Comment: I just didn't quite got you with `fork` for the `<` . I've edited my post , and posted the current code for `handleLess` . Can u please explain how & why father and son processes would help me in this case ... ?

Comment: I know about the waiting , what I don't understand is what's the purpose of using `fork()` for the `<` command ? just looking for a simple explanation , nothing more . And yes,I can `fork` all day long , but I want to use it when I have something to gain , not without a reason .

Comment: When you want to run a command, you use `execvp`. But if you do `execvp` without `fork`, the existing program (i.e. your shell) stops running. So you'll never get to process the next command.